# Laravel account password randomly changes

Tags: php, passwords, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5.0 app where users can create an account. 
Everything works fine except for one thing. When I create an account, I set the password: *password123*. I can login with this password for a few days, but then after a few days it suddenly returns me that the password does not match the account.

So I have to reset the password again.

As you can tell, this is not correct and I'd like to know how to fix this.

Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

PS. I have not added any code since I just use the standard laravel authcontroller to login.

Comment: How about your application key, did you change that?

Comment: So you say that you can login several times with this password, and the login is done without a "remember" cookie? That would indicate, that your login procedure is probably correct. Could it be, that another user can influence the password in the database, maybe the query of a new registration does update too many users?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I've ran some test and found out i was being silly. The password only got 'unknown' when i updated the User. Found that in my user update route the password gets rehashed.

Will check later if this did in fact 'change' the password.